# Returning all objects in list which have the same attribute as another object?

Tags: python

I have a class Move, which has three attributes: newPos, oldPos, and notation. Notation is a string. I generate a list of moves, and I want to check if the notation is the same for any of them. What would be the most pythonic way to do this? The cleanest solution I could think of was this :

```
duplicateNotationMoves = []
for move in moves :
    if len([m for m in moves if m.notation == move.notation]) :
        duplicateNotationMoves.append(move)
```

It works fine, but it seems inefficient and not very pythonic. Is there a cleaner way to get all the moves that have the same notation as another move in the list?

Comment: My vote would be 1) Make a list of `move.notations`. 2) Make a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from that list. 3) Find all notations where the count is greater than 1.

Comment: so you want to create a list, that contains lists that have matching notations?, almost sounds like you want to do list comprehension inside of a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cleaner way to do it in one line, it sacrifices some legibility though :

```
duplicateNotationMoves = list(filter(lambda move : len(m for m in moves if m.notation == move.notation) > 1, moves))
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? a little double list comprehension action

```
import random

class move: # i just made a simplified version that randomly makes notations
    def __init__(self):
        self.notation = str(random.randrange(1,10))
    def __repr__(self): #so it has something to print, instead of <object@blabla>
        return self.notation


moves = [move() for x in range(20)] #spawns 20 of them in a list

dup = [[y for y in moves if x.notation == y.notation] for x in moves] #double list comprehension


>>> dup
[[4, 4, 4], [7, 7, 7, 7], [1], [2, 2], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [4, 4,4], [7, 7, 7, 7], [3, 3], [7, 7, 7, 7], [4, 4, 4], [6, 6], [2, 2], [8, 8, 8, 8,8], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9], [6, 6], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [3, 3], [7, 7, 7, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#UNTESTED

# First, collect the data in a useful form:
notations = collections.Counter(move.notation for move in moves)

# If you want the notations that are duplicated:
duplicate_notations = [
    notation
    for notation, count in notations.items()
    if count > 1]

# Or, if you want the moves that have duplicate notations:
duplicate_moves = [
    move
    for move in moves
    if notations[move.notation] > 1]
```